# glsl shader strange error (on word "half")

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, precision

I have very strange shader error. Here is my shader as is:

```
#version 100
#define smooth_len 1.799999952316284 
#define half_len 1.000000000000000 


attribute mediump vec4 vertex;  // w = 0 - fade; 1 - not fade  (inner/outer)    !HAS_FADE :: 1 = ignore

// non normalized
attribute mediump vec4 dir;     // xy = rib1, zw = rib2



uniform mediump mat4 matrix;
uniform mediump mat2 rot;

uniform mediump vec3 scale;     //yz - inverse scale


uniform  lowp vec4 color;
varying  lowp vec4 v_color;



//#define smooth_len 0.9*2
//#define smooth_len 10.9*2

//#define half_len 0.5*2
//#define half_len 2.5*2


#define FULL_ZERO 0.00001
#define ONE 0.99999

#define ZERO /*0.0001*/0.001
#define HALF_AA 0.05
const mediump vec4 ZERO_HALF_VEC = vec4(ZERO, ZERO, HALF_AA, HALF_AA);

const mediump vec4 ZERO_VEC = vec4(ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO);
const mediump vec4 HALF_VEC = vec4(HALF_AA, HALF_AA, HALF_AA, HALF_AA);

const mediump vec2 HALF_LEN_VEC   = vec2(half_len, half_len);
const mediump vec2 SMOOTH_LEN_VEC = vec2(smooth_len, smooth_len);

const mediump vec2 ONE_VEC = vec2(1.0, 1.0);

#define SMOOTH_IT smooth_it.xy
#define HALF_IT   smooth_it.zw

void main(void)
{

        vec2 v        = vertex.xy;


        /*vec4 dir_norm = vec4(normalize(dir.xy),
                         normalize(dir.zw));*/
        /** just to make sure */
        vec2 len2 = vec2(dot(dir.xy,dir.xy), dot(dir.zw,dir.zw));
        vec2 inv_sqrt = inversesqrt(len2);
        vec4 dir_norm  = dir * inv_sqrt.xxyy;

        vec4 normale = vec4(-dir_norm.y, dir_norm.x, -dir_norm.w, dir_norm.z);


        float is_equal = step( dot(dir_norm.xy, dir_norm.zw), -ONE );         // if == -1 is equal



        vec4 real_dir = abs(vec4( rot * dir_norm.xy, rot * dir_norm.zw) );  // .xy = vec1, .zw = vec2

        /*vec4 smooth_half1 = step(ZERO_HALF_VEC, real_dir.xyxy);
        vec4 smooth_half2 = step(ZERO_HALF_VEC, real_dir.zwzw);

        vec4 smooth_half_it = smooth_half1 * smooth_half2;           // .xy = smooth, .zw = half
*/

        vec4 smooth = step(ZERO_VEC, real_dir);
        vec4 half = step(HALF_VEC, real_dir);

        vec2 smooth_it = smooth.xz * smooth.yw;
        vec2 half_it   = half.xz * half.yw;



/*
        smooth_it = vec2(1.0,1.0);          // 1 - enable
        half_it   = vec2(0.0,0.0);          // 0 - enable
*/
        vec2 d =  mix(HALF_LEN_VEC, SMOOTH_LEN_VEC, half_it) * smooth_it; // smooth len (for each rib)

        vec2 k = vec2( dot(normale.xy, dir_norm.zw), dot(normale.zw, dir_norm.xy) );
        k = mix(k, ONE_VEC, is_equal);      // avoid division by zero


        vec2 dres = d/k;

        vec4 offset = dir_norm * dres.yyxx;
        vec2 v_offset = mix(offset.xy + offset.zw, normale.xy*d.x, is_equal);

        //v += (v_offset * scale.yz) * (1- vertex.w);
        v_offset = v_offset - v_offset * vertex.w; // MAD
        v += (v_offset * scale.yz);


        v_color = vec4(color.xyz, color.w* vertex.w );

        gl_Position = matrix * vec4(v, vertex.z, 1.0);

}
```

And here is the **[RESULT](http://shdr.bkcore.com/#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)** 
As you can see  *error appears at "vec4 half"*. If rename "half", to lets say "half_v" it compiles.

BUT WHHHYYYY???

Comment: Well I'd expect that it's some kind of reserved word... But there is no function half in GLSL, maybe it's something specific to your card...

Comment: Did you even click on "result" in my question? That result ON YOUR card.

Comment: Yes, it works on my card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graphics card seems to implement the [`GL_NV_half_float`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/half_float.txt) extension. This extension introduces a new GLSL datatype named `half`. Half float is an IEEE 754r standard ([`binary16`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format)) half-precision data type used for values of lesser precision and range. This data type is of size 16-bits: 1 bit for sign, 5 bits for exponent and 10 bits for significand, excluding the one implicit bit.

Comment: This is correct, see also: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_:_nVidia_specific_features

Comment: Ok, but why you say "on your card"? Don't you face the same error while running "RESULT" in my question?

Comment: Yes, this implies that mine implements it too. Point is that there are cards which don't implement it where you wouldn't get that error like you and I get. (I know my Nvidia card does support it since a query on GL extensions gives many extensions out of which one of them is NV_half_float).

Comment: @legends2k - Don't you know anything about "smooth"? I got 'smooth' : syntax error syntax error on Qualcomm (Android device). Already found it. Keyword, also.

Comment: @tower120: Again [`smooth`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Interpolation_qualifiers) is an interpolation qualifer (a keyword) in GLSL. Try to avoid such words since GLSL isn't C++ you don't have namespace to save you too, so use names with some variation.

Comment: @legends2k - I'd gladly avoid them, if I'd only know what exactly I have to avoid :))

Answer (score 1):

`half` is a keyword resrved for future use, according to the [GLSL spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf)  (section 3.6 on pp20-22)

Comment: Yeah? And what about Android's OpenGL ES 2.0? Where I met that error, at first time.

Comment: @tower120: [section 3.6 of the ES language spec](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf),  pp16-17.  But the full GLSL set is likely to be reserved in future versions of GLES.